# movement of one seekBar will affect other seekBar

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-widget

I have 5 seekBar widgets in my app screen and a "total budget" editText widget that the user can initialize.
I want to achieve the affect of moving one seekBar to affect the other seekBar to move the opposite direction limited by the "total budget".
How can I achieve that affect and is it possible to make the seekBars to move simultaneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener` for this.
For every seekbar you need to set this listener and update the other seekbars' value from the `onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)` method similar to this:

```
    seekBar1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            if(fromUser){
                // update other seekbars' value
                seekBar2.setProgress();
                seekBar3.setProgress();
                seekBar4.setProgress();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });

    seekBar2.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            if(fromUser){
                // update other seekbars' value
                seekBar1.setProgress();
                seekBar3.setProgress();
                seekBar4.setProgress();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });
```